# Does Tidesdk support video/audio tags?

Tags: html, audio, video, tidesdk

Like the title ,does Tidesdk support video/audio tags?

My english is very poor，hope you can understand！

thx !!!

Answer (score 3):

You should know that OSX works fine with HTML5 audio and video tags. We are working on updated WebKit support for all platforms. Following the public release of 1.3.1, we are focusing on upgrades to the internal libraries. From there, we will have succession of releases until all libs are fully upgraded.